# How do you enable filters in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have an existing spreadsheet On Office 365 which has the ability to filter. It looks like this:

[image: Spreadsheet]

Basically, it's possible to filter/sort based on the header column, and it's easy.
(Sorry for blurring, it's potentially sensitive information)

Now I have a new sheet... and cannot figure out for the life of me how to enable this feature, where you can click on the header row and decide sorting/filtering

How do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select any cell in the sheet that has data, and the click `Data > Fliter` from the ribbon. This should bring up the filter dropdowns.

[image]

But rather than doing that, I'd instead select the whole table in the new sheet --select a cell, press `Ctrl+A`-- and then go to `Home > Format as Table` and pick a desired table formatting style (ensure the "My data has headers box" is ticked if you have headers). Formatting the data as a table makes it a "proper" table aka `ListObject`, and enables filtering as well as easier naming and structured referencing.

[image]

Comment: That's precisely what I needed and what I was missing. Thank you a MILLION Preston.